# Excess comma replace issue after creating auto links from tags

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace, str-replace

My issue is inside the if statement below. My tags structure is like this: tag1, tag2, tag3

I achieved auto linking of each tag of each article but if the number of tags is more than 1, I need to replace two characters that are 1 comma+1 space character and inside the related `<p></p>` couple. These 2 characters {1 comma+1 space} are before the last `</p>` tag. Explicitly I mean:

My input is (html source):

```
<p>Etiketler: <a href="http://localhost/türkçe/etiketler/tag1">tag1</a>, <a href="http://localhost/türkçe/etiketler/tag2">tag2</a>, </p>
```

and my desired output is (html source)

```
<p>Etiketler: <a href="http://localhost/türkçe/etiketler/tag1">tag1</a>, <a href="http://localhost/türkçe/etiketler/tag2">tag2</a></p>
```

my custom function is below> Now, you see the `preg_replace` but I also tried `str_replace`. My encoding is `utf-8` if it helps. I read the php.net manual for these 2 functions but I couldn't get rid of those 2 characters.

Can you help me please?

```
function etiketleri_link_yap ($article_tags)
{
    $array_of_tags = explode(", ", $article_tags);
    if (count($array_of_tags) >= 2) 
        {
            $ely ='';
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_of_tags); $i++) 
                {
                    $ely .= '<a href="'.sitenin_koku.'türkçe/etiketler/'.$array_of_tags[$i].'">'.$array_of_tags[$i].'</a>, ';
                }
            $arabunu ="/<\/a>, <\/p>/"; $degistir  = '</a></p>';
            $ely = preg_replace($arabunu, $degistir, $ely);
            return $ely;
        }
    else
        {
            $ely ='<a href="'.sitenin_koku.'türkçe/etiketler/'.$array_of_tags[0].'">'.$array_of_tags[0].'</a>';
            return $ely;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no closing `<p>` tag in your `$ely` variable, just `<a>` tags so your regex never matches.

I would build an array of tags / tag links and implode them at the end:

```
$links = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_of_tags); $i++) 
{
   $links[] = '<a href="'.sitenin_koku.'türkçe/etiketler/'.$array_of_tags[$i].'">'.$array_of_tags[$i].'</a>';
}
$ely = implode(', ', $links);
```

By the way, I would also use a `foreach` to loop over `$array_of_tags` but if you are sure the index starts at 0 and there are no missing indices, the result should be the same.

Comment: your code is working perfectly. but still I don't know what was my mistake. If you also tell me about my mistake, I'll be very happy. regards.

Comment: @Andre Chenier There is no closing `<p>` tag in your `$ely` variable, just `<a>` tags so your regex never matches.